# HikariCP and MySQL versions

Tags: mysql, hikaricp

How can I find which version of HikariCP is tied to which version of MySQL? 
I could not find in [changes in HikariCP](http://raw.githubusercontent.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/dev/CHANGES).

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Hikari's MySQL Configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration):

> A typical MySQL configuration for HikariCP might look something like this:
>
> ```
> jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simpsons
> user=test
> password=test
> dataSource.cachePrepStmts=true
> dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
> dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
> dataSource.useServerPrepStmts=true
> dataSource.useLocalSessionState=true
> dataSource.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
> dataSource.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
> dataSource.cacheServerConfiguration=true
> dataSource.elideSetAutoCommits=true
> dataSource.maintainTimeStats=false
> ```

It uses [jdbcUrl configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names):

> The MySQL DataSource is known to be broken with respect to network timeout support. Use jdbcUrl configuration instead.
>
> <strike>MySQL  Connector/J com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</strike>